# IIS Module for Blocking Heavy Site Traffic

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, module

## Question

Hello All,

A little background on my issue...  I currently have a site built for the ISP I work for that displays messages to users based on their billing status.  When they are in Non-Pay I display a Non-Pay message and if they are in Abuse, I display an abuse message, etc.  The traffic is generated by a Cisco SCE that redirects the end user's HTTP traffic to my site.

The issue that I'm seeing is excessive traffic.  I beleive the traffic might be P2P traffic, automatic updates, or anything else of the sort.  Basically anything that uses port 80 is redirected by the SCE to my page.

The solution I'm trying to enforce on my server is to put a module in place that blocks users based on their hit count.  So if they exceed a threshold during a certain duration of time, they will be redirected to another page which will hopefully bring the load off of the processor since it won't have to do all of the SQL lookups and intelligence that takes place in the ASP.NET page.

However, when I try enforcing a module that I built, it actually has the opposite result (increases CPU load).  The module uses an in memory table that is stored in Application State which it uses to track the requests by IP.  Here is the code for the module:

```
public class IpHitCount : IHttpModule
{
    const string tableKey = "appIpLog";

    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(checkHitCount);
    }

    #endregion

    private void checkHitCount(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cast the parameter into a HttpApp object
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        // make sure that this is the user's first request for the app
        // (all first requests are routed through main)
        if (app.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains("main.aspx"))
        {
            // If the in memory table does not exist, then create it
            if (app.Application[tableKey] == null)
            {
                app.Application[tableKey] = CreateTable();
            }

            DataSet ds = (DataSet)app.Application[tableKey];
            DataTable tbl = ds.Tables["IpTable"];
            DeleteOldEntries(tbl);

            string filter = string.Format("ip = '{0}'", app.Request.UserHostAddress);
            DataRow[] matchedRows = tbl.Select(filter);

            if (matchedRows.Length > 0)
            {
                DataRow matchedRow = matchedRows[0];
                if ((int)matchedRow["hitCount"] > 4)
                {
                    app.Response.Redirect("HitCountExceeded.htm", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    matchedRow["hitCount"] = (int)matchedRow["hitCount"] + 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow newEntry = tbl.NewRow();
                newEntry["timestamp"] = DateTime.Now;
                newEntry["hitCount"] = 1;
                newEntry["ip"] = app.Request.UserHostAddress;
                tbl.Rows.Add(newEntry);
            }                
        }
    }

    private DataSet CreateTable()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable table = new DataTable("IpTable");

        DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("timestamp", typeof(DateTime));
        col1.AutoIncrement = false;
        col1.DefaultValue = DateTime.Now;
        col1.ReadOnly = false;
        col1.Unique = false;

        DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("ip", typeof(string));
        col1.AutoIncrement = false;
        col1.ReadOnly = false;  
        col1.Unique = false;

        DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("hitCount", typeof(int));
        col1.AutoIncrement = false;
        col1.ReadOnly = false;
        col1.Unique = false;

        table.Columns.Add(col1);
        table.Columns.Add(col2);
        table.Columns.Add(col3);

        ds.Tables.Add(table);

        return ds;
    }

    private void DeleteOldEntries(DataTable tbl)
    {
        // build the where clause
        string filter = "timestamp < '" + DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5.0).ToString() + "'";

        // run the query against the table
        DataRow[] rowsToDelete = tbl.Select(filter);

        // individually delete each row returned
        foreach (DataRow row in rowsToDelete)
        {
            row.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

So what I am wondering is the following: Is there something you can see that I am doing wrong in the module, which might be causing the high CPU utilization?  Is there an alternative way that I should be blocking this traffic?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
C

---

## Solution

I have changed the code in the module to only run the delete section every 1 minute:

```
    if (app.Application[deletedKey] == null)
    app.Application[deletedKey] = DateTime.Now;

    DateTime deletedDate = (DateTime)app.Application[deletedKey];

    if (DateTime.Now >= deletedDate.AddMinutes(1))
    {
        DeleteOldEntries(tbl);
        app.Application[deletedKey] = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

I also added some code that I believe indexes the IP column of my dataset.  It doesn't seem right though, so I'm not certain it is doing what I'm intending it to do:

```
    DataColumn[] key = new DataColumn[1];
    key[0] = col1;

    table.PrimaryKey = key;

    ds.Tables.Add(table);
```

After making the two above changes, the CPU load seems to have decreased dramatically.  I imagine that our SQL server is also thanking God now that it can finally breath.

Thank you for all of the help!!

Comment: I don't know much about using Windows as a server, but isn't this something that your web server and/or firewall should be able to take care of together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that I'd try:

- The first thing I see is that you're calling the "DeleteOldEntries" sub every time this code is run, which causes it to do a scan through the entire DataTable on every pass. Is there another way you could limit this to only run at certain times? If not a timer that runs it every 15 seconds, then maybe a second variable in the state (like "ExecCount") that increments every time "CheckHitCount" is run, so that you only purge every 10th or 20th time through? This way, you can avoid this potentially expensive section of the code on every run.
- Another option is adding an index to your DataTable. I'm not sure how .NET handles lookups in DataTables, but perhaps this would be of interest to you: [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx)

Can you use something like ANTS Profiler to see where the most time is spent during execution? Since I imagine this page is being called many, many times/second, any way you can lower the impact even a little would make a big difference.

If you get some results but still aren't happy, make sure you modify your question to add the new info so we can keep working towards a solution that you're happy with.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to remember that the DataSet is going to be in memory, and to search over the DataSet, it's going to take a lot of CPU cycles to find the records you are looking for.

Add to that the fact that since this is a web application, you are going to get a lot of hits, so you are going to end up calling this routine very, very often.

My recommendation would be to store the hit counts in a database server and then update and query the server to see if the hit count is exceeded.  It will be able to handle the load, as well as handle the size of the data set that you are going to query.